# Getting nodes to update with content type changes in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, xampp, drush

I have a local build of Drupal 7 with Xampp on windows.  When I add a field to a node's content type, I see the field appear *last*, no matter what order I put the field in Content types > [myType] > Manage fields.  I would tend to think this is a cache problem... but I've tried Configuration > Performance > Clear all caches, and the order of the fields does not update.

For example, I currently have an image field, a display title field, and a body field.  In the Manage Fields lightbox, the order of the fields is:

1. **Image**
2. **Display Title** (New field, I'm not using the default title because Drupal always places is above the image instead of after)
3. **Body**

However, on the page the order is

1. **Image**
2. **Body**
3. **Display Title**

This is not just a trick caused by funky CSS—the PHP is actually creating the HTML in the wrong order.

I'm guessing that Drupal updates when you add a new field (which appears last by default when created).  It *does not* update when fields are repositioned in Manage Fields, leaving the title last on the page, although it's second in Manage Fields.

And yes, I did save the configuration after repositioning the fields in Manage Fields.  I've also cleared the browser cache, and restarted the browser.

How can I get Drupal to display the fields in the order they appear in Manage Fields?

---

P.S. I also downloaded Drush to see if it could clear the cache.  The Drush command line works, but none of the tutorials I found actually explain how to hook Drush up to a *local* install, only how to SSH into remote server... I typed in 'drush cc' my drupal folder, but I don't know if Drush actually did anything since I don't know how to make drush connect to my localhost.

Comment: Are the fields in the incorrect order when you're *editing* a node or when you're *viewing* the node or both?

Comment: right order when editing, wrong order when viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but 'Manage Display' does not, in fact, Manage the Display.  It manages the order of the fields when editing a content type, but does not influence the order in which they are displayed.

So, I was looking at it again (figuring I would have to edit  into printing individual fields in the content)... and I was looking at the Devel tab (Developer module), and clicked 'render.'  Some how that fixed / updated the page, and the title jumped from the bottom to above the body text.

Still not sure exactly what controls the order that fields display in... Maybe I'm a complete n00b, but if the info's out there, it's hard to find.

Comment: You know, sometimes it's a caching issues -- if this was fixed randomly without you changing anything, it may have been that you needed to clear your Drupal cache.  ;=)

Comment: What killed me during Drupal dev is that I cleared both the Drupal cache and the browser cache, and then would see the change about a day later... If it's a Drupal caching issue, then either clearing the cache does not consistently work, or it is really, really slow.